# Angular Isolate Scope for nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, isolate-scope

I'm attempting to set up an angular app with three directives - container, getter and setter. I've put it up at 
http://plnkr.co/edit/CoYLuVbiZTFWvNsN5r5L?p=preview

```
<container>
    <getter name="first"></getter>
    <getter name="second"></getter>
    <setter name="setter"></setter>
</container>
```

`Container` has a scope with the variable `value` which can be read by `getter` and `setter`. `getter` displays the value whilst `setter` both displays and changes the value.

```
    angular.module("app").directive('container', function() {
      return {
        scope: {},
        template: '<h1>Container <input ng-model="value"/></h1><div ng-transclude>SCOPED1</div>',
        transclude: true,
        controller: ["$scope", "$window", function($scope, $window){
            $scope.value = "Hello"
        }]
      };
    });
```

Both `getter` and `setter` have their own isolate scope but also have a two-way binding to the `container` scope to get and set `value`.

```
    angular.module("app").directive('getter', function() {
      return {
        require: '^container',
        scope: {
            name: '@',
            value:'='
          },
        template: '<p>I am getter {{name}}, I got {{value}}</p>'
      };
    });
```

At the moment, `getter` and `setter` can access the `container` scope using `$scope.$parent.$parent.value` but that seems way too clunky. I thought using `scope:{value:'='}` would set up two way bindings but apparently not.

What am I doing wrong?

http://plnkr.co/edit/CoYLuVbiZTFWvNsN5r5L?p=preview

Comment: This may be what you want?
http://plnkr.co/edit/poW8JNbf1wrGNb7K0WBy?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive isolate scope is not automatically linked to variables in the parent scope. You must tell the directive that `value` is supposed to be `value` in the parent scope, the same way you supply the directive name.

```
<container value="value">
    <getter name="first" value="value"></getter>
    <getter name="second" value="value"></getter>
    <setter name="setter" value="value"></setter>
</container>
```

Comment: Thanks for that - Unfortunately I've corrected the code (http://plnkr.co/edit/CoYLuVbiZTFWvNsN5r5L?p=preview) but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you expecting it to pull the value from the container directive? That isn't hooked up to the parent scope at all.

Comment: Oh sorry that was a mistake in my .js file - along with @Sam 's comment it all makes sense!