# multiple instances of same directive, how to isolate scope in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angularjs-scope, angular2-directives

I have a same select-option list in dynamically created widgets. So whenever I select an option from widget #1, the same option is also selected for other widgets.
How to isolate their scope to identify each option from widgets. I have checked few links like: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496217/angular-isolate-scope-for-nested-directives) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949138/multiple-instance-of-same-angular-directive-mess-up-scope-variables). But **I need to do it in Angular 4**. Any leads?

#### dashboardConfig.component.html  ###

**This part to select no. of Widget**

```
 <div class="edit-dashboard">      
     <select [(ngModel)] = "widgetCounter" (change)="widgetCountFunc()">
        <option *ngFor="let i of ArrayOfNumbersForWidget">{{i}}</option>
     <select>
 </div>
```

**this part to create widgets**

```
  <div class="widget-area" *ngFor="let i of widgetObjList ">    

    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption (change)="selectedOptForThisWidget()">
         <option *ngFor="let opt of ListOfOpts" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
     </select>
  </div>
```

#### dashboardConfig.component.ts ###

```
 widgetCountFunc(){
     this.ListOfOpts = ArrayMaker(this.widgetCounter);
           }
```

> ArrayMaker() this part creates an array of selected number, not elaborated

So the issue occurs with     `[(ngModel)] = "selectedOption"`.

1) How to select individual option for each of the widgets?
   e.g. For Widget #1 -> Option #2; Widget #2 -> Option #5 etc.

2) How to show the pre-selected options for each widget through 
    `"selectedOption"` assuming we have a json file of the widgets and corresponding options?

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Post HTML code and component code - behind.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] for your problem.

Comment: Each component **should** receive a unique instance of any directive placed on it. If they are elements that require unique names, its possible you are giving them all the same identifier and that is why they are exhibiting the same behavior... but as other users mention, impossible to know without your code.

Comment: minimal code added.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you create angular2/4 components instead of angular1 custom directives?

> solution
>   Create new component for individual  selections and use component selectors inside *ngFor iteration and pass appropriate values inside component from the selector.
>
> advantages 
>   It will create individual instances, which you required.
>
> disadvantages
>   Since it's individual instances you need to handle component objects individually.